# get the values of a hash as integer instead of string in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have a hash getting in the controller from coffeescript:

```
h = {"1"=>"[2, 44]", "3"=>"[50]", "4"=>"[43, 42]", "9"=>"[48, 40, 45, 41]"}
```

Actually, I need the value as integers,but here it returns as a string like the below:

```
h["9"] , it will return  "[48, 40, 45, 41]" .
```

How can I get it as an integer array.Please help

Thanks

Comment: I prefer Sebastian's answer, but you could write `h.transform_values { |s| s.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i) } #=> {"1"=>[2, 44], "3"=>[50], "4"=>[43, 42], "9"=>[48, 40, 45, 41]}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could parse each value as a JSON:

```
h.transform_values { |value| JSON.parse(value) }
# => {"1"=>[2, 44], "3"=>[50], "4"=>[43, 42], "9"=>[48, 40, 45, 41]}
```